# Reading line before and after map method in stream - Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I try to make program which would be hashing lines from file and print that in console.

My code:

```
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file)) {
                System.out.println(file.getFileName().toString());
                stream.map(Main::hashIt)
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

output:

```
230ffjsdlfjsdlfj3290
fsdf09sd903208320ffd
239023590sa0d09sjdsf
```

I want that output:

```
line1 : 230ffjsdlfjsdlfj3290
line2 : fsdf09sd903208320ffd
line3 : 239023590sa0d09sjdsf
```

Is that possible to print line and after that result of my `hashIt` method without any new structures like map etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
stream.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " : " + hashIt(s)));
```